# Storing data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this assessment project from a company which involves HTML,CSS and JavaScript. They sent me a zip file and I'm supposed to implement the app (which is an address book) using the node.js they sent.

The problem is I don't know much about node.js. I've been reading a bunch of stuff online but I still couldn't figure out how to store data. The instructions said that the data is already managed by the server and can be interacted using this API:

API:

```
GET - api/contacts/
params: none
returns list of contacts


GET - api/contacts/:id
params: {
    id: int
}
returns contact with given id or null if contact does not exist


POST - api/contacts/
data: {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string
} 
returns saved contact


PUT - api/contacts/
data: {
    id: int,
    contact: 
    {
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string,
        email: string
    }
}
return updated contact


DELETE - api/contacts/:id
params: {
    id: int
}
returns a true or false depending on if contact was successfully deleted
```

I don't know how to approach this problem. This is for a front-end internship position. I thought about using ajax or something but I think I may be just making it more complicated than it has to be because that's backend stuff. There has to be an easier way of doing this like maybe use a function/method or something?

### Update

I spent all Monday night brushing up on JavaScript (I'm a senior at university that doesn't teach JS so everything is self-taught) then I even studied backbone.js that same night. I thought it was a bit complicated so I decided to not do it that way because I don't want the company to think I know backbone.js.

I didn't even know what to do in the beginning because I didn't know node.js either so I also had to do a lot of reading about that. I was thinking of several ways of approaching it and just really needed some guide but couldn't find any.

Anyway thank you very much for the example. I learn best by seeing examples.

Comment: You said they sent you the node js stuff … so isn't the backend side of things done already?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a restful API from the nodejs file sent to you, so using [AJAX requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would be the right thing to do.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:nodeport/api/contacts/'
  data: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', email: 'j.smith@example.com' }
  success: function(data, status, xhr) { window.alert('Contact '+data.firstName+' saved'); }
});
```

would store the data in the server and return the saved contact in the success callback.

Comment: The question says "They sent me a zip file and I'm supposed to implement the app (which is an address book) using the node.js they sent." and "This is for a front-end internship position": Presumably that means the node.js is *providing* those URLs and the requests to them should be made by the browser. It really doesn't sound like the problem is writing an HTTP client in node.

Comment: Indeed I misread that part, pardon me for that one. You're correct on that one. An MVC framework like backbone could aid in the development of such an app.

Comment: I found a tutorial on Youtube that does this app using backbone.js but I don't want to copy the code entirely. I want to do this using my own code. Just need to know how to store data. Plus I don't really know backbone.js, I don't want to give the company an impression that I do. Could anyone give me an example of an AJAX request that uses this API endpoints? It would be very helpful.

Comment: If the nodejs file doesn't save the data, you should implement a simple [datastore](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/datastore). If you mean the client side, look into a [storage polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#wiki-web-storage-localstorage-and-sessionstorage) to have a cross-browser (read non html5) compatible solution.
Just browse some docs and choose one you feel comfortable with.

Comment: As the other commenter mentioned, all the back-end is already done so the data is being saved. I just don't know how to use these end points to save and retrieve the data.

Comment: I've added an example to save data, retrieving is basically the same thing with type: 'GET' and 'http://localhost:nodeport/api/contacts/12' as url.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that later when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework where you can easely setup routes for your API. For data storage, use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), which is kind of abstraction for mongodb with some helpful stuff out of the box.

That's basically all.

Comment: But it looks like you have it done already. It's just a list of API endpoints which you should use for your application. So it's all front-end work need to be done.

Comment: I read about the MongoDB stuff but do I need to install it? I don't get how to integrate it with the node.js they sent in a zip file.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured because this is just front-end stuff. Could you pls show me an example that uses these end-points ?

Comment: $.get('api/contacts/', function (res) {console.log(res)});

Answer (score 0):

I think the backend data is handled by the node.js, leave it. Knowing the **REST** api you should know with **GET** you get some data, with **POST** you create and store data, with **PUT** you update data and with **DELETE** you delete data. Each call will give you an answer so you know your ajax call was handled well by the backend. As a starter you are, I suggest you use jQuery ajax calls and try to get it done.